# Android deep linking not loading from browser, even from simple tutorial

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, deep-linking

I'm having trouble getting deep linking to work in my android application, so I found the most bare-bones tutorial I could and it's still just opening the browser when I click on the link.  All of this is pasted from my code not the tutorial, in case I pasted something wrong.  Even with this

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.DeepLinkTest">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- as we want to open main activity from our link so we are specifying
            only in main activity or we can specify that in different activity as well -->
        <!-- on below line we are adding intent filter to our MainActivity -->
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- below line is to set the action to our intent to view -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <!-- on below line we are adding a default category to our intent -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <!-- on below line we are adding a category to make our app browsable -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <!-- on below line we are specifying the host name and
                the scheme type from which we will be calling our app -->
            <data
                android:host="www.chaitanyamunje.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- below is the same filter as above just the scheme is changed to http -->
        <!-- so we can open our app with the url starting with https and http as well -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="www.chaitanyamunje.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package me.paxana.deeplinktest

import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  // creating a variable for our text view
  private lateinit var messageTV: TextView
  private var uri: Uri? = null

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // initializing our variable
    messageTV = findViewById(R.id.idTVMessage)
    // getting the data from our intent in our uri.
    uri = intent.data

    // checking if the uri is null or not.
    if (uri != null) {
      // if the uri is not null then we are getting
      // the path segments and storing it in list.
      val parameters = uri!!.pathSegments

      // after that we are extracting string
      // from that parameters.
      val param = parameters[parameters.size - 1]

      // on below line we are setting that
      // string to our text view which
      // we got as params.
      messageTV.text = param
    }
  }
}
```

The result of using the App Link Testing feature of android studio to load https://www.chaitanyamunje.com/hello/GeeksForGeeks

[image: Browser showing "This site can't be reached. Check if there is a typo in chaitanyamunje.com. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN."]

Comment: Did you set up your `assetlinks.json` file as is described [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks)? Also, are you clicking on a link in a Web page to navigate to the deeplink, or are you typing in the deeplink in the address bar. The address bar approach generally does not work. Finally, what Web browser are you using? It looks like Chrome, which is fine, but some other browsers (Firefox, Samsung Internet) do not have deeplinks enabled by default.

Comment: I do have assetlinks.json set up with the SHA-256 for the debug and the release keys.  I'm using the "Test on Device or Emulator" tool in android studio, and I'm using chrome on my device and the default browser on the emulator (I'm assuming chrome).

Comment: That screenshot does not look like an emulator. Regardless, have you tried [the manual verification instructions](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#manual-verification)?

Comment: [Similar!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73512287/6576302)

Answer (score 0):

A very common issue faced by me many times. People often add `https` in `android:scheme` to make that url secure. I have no idea of why that doesn't open the app. But, in my case, removing that intent filter made the app to open for me.

Let me know if its useful